# How To Convert object HTMLInputElement to javascript array

Tags: javascript, csv

I have to take input from the user in CSV, and then extract values from a specific table. 
I have used the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to extract content from the CSV, but I'm getting object HTMLInputElement in the console.

This is my code

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
var blob = new Blob([input], {
    encoding:"UTF-8",
    type: "text/csv;charset=UTF-8"
});

input.addEventListener('change',function(e) {
  console.log(input.files)
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(blob);

},false);
```

I should get the content from the csv, but I'm getting **object HTMLInputElement**

Comment: The Blob is `HTMLInputElement.files[0]`. You don't need to create one, get the one your user provides. So your code should become `var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]'); input.addEventListener('change',function(e) {   const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]); }`